# For/ Do loop on a lists of two variables

Tags: procedural-programming

I am trying to get an output of the following kind

```
Out = Do[Evaluate[f[x,y]],{x,table1},{y,table2}]
```

Here Out is a N-times-1 dimensional array/list and N is the size of table1 and table2.

I have been trying Do/For loops with various errors. Could anyone please help me on how to go about this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134609/why-should-i-avoid-the-for-loop-in-mathematica/134610#134610

Comment: I'd like to add that the use of `Evaluate` in this code snippet is most likely not necessary or even desirable. `Evaluate` is a symbol you should only start using when you get a good feel for how the Mathematica evaluator works and understand how attributes like `HoldAll` work.

Answer (score 5):

`Do` returns `Null`. `Do` is used for its side effect. Instead, use the sister function `Table`:

```
Table[f[x, y], {x, {1, 2, 3, 4}}, {y, {10, 20, 30}}]
{{f[1, 10], f[1, 20], f[1, 30]}, {f[2, 10], f[2, 20], 
  f[2, 30]}, {f[3, 10], f[3, 20], f[3, 30]}, {f[4, 10], f[4, 20], 
  f[4, 30]}}
```

Comment: Thank you. How does the above get modified if my requirement is to create out[i] = [f[x[i],y[i]]], where i varies from {1,Length[x]} ?

Comment: Okay. I just used something like the following list = {};
For[i = 1, i <= Length[x], ++i, 
 list = Append[list, f[x,y] /. {x ->x[[i]], y -> y[[i]]}]]. And this seems to work. Please let me know if there is a better way of doing this. Thanks.

Comment: @Prag, you should ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you use `Outer`, which enables you to get rid of dummy indexes. By just using @user21 's `table1` and `table2`,

```
table1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
table2 = {10, 20, 30};
Outer[f, table1, table2]
```

returns

> {{f[1, 10], f[1, 20], f[1, 30]},
>     {f[2, 10], f[2, 20], f[2, 30]},
>     {f[3, 10], f[3, 20], f[3, 30]},
>     {f[4, 10], f[4, 20], f[4, 30]}}

Pay attention to how `Outer` distributes `table1` and `table2`; and I think this is one of the typical examples to avoid explicit loops in Wolfram language.

If you want a 1D vector output rather than a 2D matrix, check `Tuples`  (or just `Transpose`) and `Apply` to level one (shorthanded as `@@@`).

---

**Update**

In the previous last paragraph, I mean, if your two tables have equal length and you want just to pick corresponding entries from them as the function's arguments, you could use:

```
tables = {{a, b, c}, {x, y, z}};
f @@@ Transpose@tables
```

returns

> {f[a, x], f[b, y], f[c, z]}

But I find a better alternative, `MapThread`:

```
MapThread[f, tables]
```